# Should /config/passport.js appear in my root /config folder in Sails.js?

Tags: sails.js

Sorry for the n00b question.  I'm trying to [configure](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth#2-configure) sails-auth with a sails.js project.

I get the feeling the file should appear in `MyProject/config/passport.js`, but I can only see it in `MyProject/node_modules/sails-auth/config/passport.js`.  Should I move it to `MyProject/config`?  Or leave it there (with a symlink maybe)?  Or maybe something didn't work right with my installation...

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned the error I got when installing sails-auth: `npm WARN EBUNDLEOVERRIDE Replacing bundled sails-auth > sails-generate-entities with new installed version`.  Makes me suspect a faulty install.  [This issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10394#issuecomment-157780514) might be the culprit.  I will try again when npm 3.5.0 comes out.

Comment: after installing passport package, you need to create a file `[your-sails-app]/config/passport.js` and there implement passport js logic